# Boolean indexing with MultiIndex df (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a MultiIndex dataframe that I'm trying to index in to based on value ranges in my columns and the outermost index levels. So, using the example below, e.g. I'm trying to select the values from `v2` that are index `l2` where `v1 > 12`

I can achieve this using multiple index statements, such as: 
`df[df.v1>12].loc['l2', 'v2']`, but this seems less than ideal. Is there a way to condense this in to a single statement?

I've been trying to figure out how to use `pd.IndexSlice`, but can't seem to wrap my head around what the examples in the MultiIndex section of the docs are doing.

```
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'v1': range(10, 15), 'v2':range(5, 0, -1)}) 
                for i in range(2)], keys=['l1', 'l2'])

      v1  v2
l1 0  10   5
   1  11   4
   2  12   3
   3  13   2
   4  14   1
l2 0  10   5
   1  11   4
   2  12   3
   3  13   2
   4  14   1
```

Comment: Please don't use values like the string `'l2'` and the integer `12` in the same code sample.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [slicers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers) for selecting and then modified [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `loc` for select column `v2`:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df1 = df.loc[idx['l2', :], :]
print (df1)
      v1  v2
l2 0  10   5
   1  11   4
   2  12   3
   3  13   2
   4  14   1

print (df1.loc[df1.v1 > 12, 'v2'])
l2  3    2
    4    1
Name: v2, dtype: int32
```

Another solution with [`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
df1 = df.xs('l2')
print (df1)
   v1  v2
0  10   5
1  11   4
2  12   3
3  13   2
4  14   1

print (df1.loc[df1.v1 > 12, 'v2'])
3    2
4    1
Name: v2, dtype: int32
```

---

```
df1 = df.xs('l2', drop_level=False)
print (df1)
      v1  v2
l2 0  10   5
   1  11   4
   2  12   3
   3  13   2
   4  14   1

print (df1.loc[df1.v1 > 12, 'v2'])
l2  3    2
    4    1
Name: v2, dtype: int32
```

Solution with selecting first level of index by [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html), last if need remove first level use [`droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html) or [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df1 = df.loc[(df.v1 > 12) & (df.index.get_level_values(0) == 'l2'), 'v2']
df1.index = df1.index.droplevel(0)
#df1 = df1.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
print (df1)
3    2
4    1
Name: v2, dtype: int32
```

---

Example with `IndexSlice`:

Select all values in first level and in second from `1` to `3` (thanks *piRSquared*):

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
print (df.loc[idx[:, 1:3], :])
      v1  v2
l1 1  11   4
   2  12   3
   3  13   2
l2 1  11   4
   2  12   3
   3  13   2
```

Comment: @piRSquared - Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I guess my real question is whether there was a way to achieve this without having to chain together multiple passes of indexing into different parts of the dataframe. Other than using `get_level_values`, which I think is somewhat clunky, the answer seems to be that there isn't a less verbose way than how I'm doing it already.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Is imposible use boolean indexing with selecting by index together. If check [cookbook](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html#dataframes) there is similar sample [29] - select by mask for column with mask for index. Nice day and good luck.